# How to add figure at particular location in draw2d?

Tags: javascript, draw2d-js

I want  to add label at start or end position of connection. But here I did not found locator except ManhattanMidpointLocator. So how can I do this? How can I place label at where on connection?
Please find my code as below,

```
draw2d.LabelConnection = function() {
  draw2d.Connection.call(this);
  this.sourcePort = null;
  this.targetPort = null;
  this.lineSegments = [];
  this.setColor(new draw2d.Color(0, 255, 0));
  this.setLineWidth(2);

  var label = new draw2d.Label("Message");
  label.setBackgroundColor(new draw2d.Color(230, 230, 250));
  label.setBorder(new draw2d.LineBorder(1));
  this.addFigure(label, new draw2d.Locator());
};

draw2d.LabelConnection.prototype = new draw2d.Connection();
draw2d.LabelConnection.prototype.type = "draw2d.LabelConnection";
```

The above code shows label at (0,0) position.
plz help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

**Connection.getStartPoint()** to determine the start poit of the connection instead
to retrieve all segments of the connection.

Greetings

Comment: I used Connection.getStartPoint() method it gives me error locator.relocate()  is not a function. Please help me out. I tried to implement relocate() method but it dose not seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you mean by "any location" but if you implement your own locator it's pretty straightforward.

Look at the code of the ManhattanMidpointLocator. In the relocate function you know everything about the connection on the canvas. From that you just invent a calculation for the position of the label.

Comment: I want to locate this label at start position instead on mid position. So how can i do this? i used Locator() but it locate it on (0,0) position. plz help?

Answer (score 0):

Now working with Graphiti in place of Draw2D but the code for your locator should look as follow (didn't tested) :

```
draw2d.StartConnectionLocator=function(/*:draw2d.Connection*/ connection)
{
  draw2d.ConnectionLocator.call(this,connection);
};
draw2d.StartConnectionLocator.prototype.relocate=function(/*:draw2d.Figure*/ target)
{
   var conn = this.getConnection();

   var points = conn.getPoints();
   var index = Math.floor((points.getSize() -2) / 2);
   if (points.getSize() <= index+1)
      return; 

   var startPoint = points.get(0);
   var myPosition = new draw2d.Point();
   myPosition.x = startPoint.x +5;
   myPosition.y = startPoint.y +5;

   target.setPosition(myPosition.x,myPosition.y);
};
```

Comment: As Andreas suggested you can use connection.getStartPoint() in place of var startPoint = points.get(0);

Comment: I used connection.getStartPoint() but it gives me error locator.relocate() is not a function. So please help me out how should i call relocate method. find my code below        draw2d.ContextmenuConnection = function(src, target) {
 draw2d.Connection.call(this);
 this.sourceAnchor.setOwner(src);
 this.targetAnchor.setOwner(target);
 var label = new draw2d.Label("Message");
 this.addFigure(label, this.getStartPoint());
 var arrowConnector = new draw2d.ArrowConnectionDecorator();
 arrowConnector.setBackgroundColor(new draw2d.Color(0, 255, 0));
};